# Import script that maintains data integrity w/ zero downtime

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

## Background

I'm writing a import script which is fairly computationally expensive and results in many insert and update database queries. My intention is to store the database on an EBS volume and use EC2's command-line tools to launch a c1.xlarge instance, perform the import (writing to the EBS volume) and self-destruct on completion (to save $).

On instance termination, the EBS volume (that contains all the imported data) is then programatically attached and mounted to the machine that contains my webserver.

By using this scheme, the webserver machine can continue to respond to HTTP requests without being:

1. CPU and RAM overloaded.
2. Serving incomplete data while the import is running.
3. Wasting resources ( Being an expensive instance-type. )

## Question

Is this a sound approach? Is it essentially how companies that manage large amounts of data are able to do so without downtime, whilst keeping up-to-date? Good books or blog posts on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

I would posit that if you have a single webserver and are concerned about the cost of a c1.xlarge for a short period of time, you can tolerate slightly more than zero downtime.  The setup you're describing sounds fine, just realize that one you turn off the DB on the c1.xlarge, your downtime starts ticking until the DB is up and your app reconfigured to point to the local instance of the DB.  Figure that'll be a few minutes, so plan accordingly - perhaps with a maintenance page or if you app can work off cached data / in read-only mode, do that.

Or if you're using a supported DB, just use RDS.  That'll probably get you a lot closer to zero downtime with less work.  You'll pay something for it, but the multi-AZ failover is worth the price of admission.

And no, this is not how a large company with lots of data would do it.  They'd most likely use replication, ensure the data is on a few different servers, and then failover the master.  That's also what you get with RDS.

Comment: Maybe I am conceptually over-engineering at too early of a stage -- early-morning downtime is acceptable, I suppose, but I'm failing to recognize where this downtime will come from? Once the import is complete, the EBS is detached from xlarge and attached and mounted to webserver. When the volume is attached and mounted, it takes the place of the old volume. This will be completely transparent to the database  itself, so it will not need a restart. RDS is unfortunately not an option -- Postgres ;)

Comment: "is detached from xlarge and attached and mounted to webserver".  The existing RDBMS cannot be online when that happens.  PG won't be happy if you swap out a mounted filesystem underneath it.  Plan on shutting down PG, mounting the disk, and bringing PG back online.  And be sure your instances are in sync before you shut down the one on the webserver.  To do that, you'll need to stop the webserver briefly, otherwise you can't guarantee that your import job has processed the newest record from your webapp.

Comment: Thx for your help. Let me be more clear -- Postgres itself is sitting on the **Root volume** -- only the data directory is set to the location of the new mount. In other words, `data_directory = '/ebs-postgres/main/'` is set in `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf`. Will it still be an issue?

Comment: Yes, still a problem.  You cannot expect PG to be happy if you swap out its data files from underneath it.  It has open filehandles and such for these files, and if you mount a new volume on top of that directory - it will still reference the old files (they're still open, just no longer visible!).  Maybe you should do a trial run and convince yourself first.  :)